# Strange MySQL view issues

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL view defined like this:

```
SELECT
    group_concat(`h`.`name` SEPARATOR ',') AS `hosts`,
    `m`.`id` AS `slo_application_id`,
    `s`.`application` AS `application`,
    `s`.`slo_conformance` AS `slo_conformance`,
    `s`.`hourly_conformance` AS `hourly_conformance`,
    `s`.`date` AS `date`,
    `m`.`slo_profile` AS `slo_profile`
FROM
    (
        (
            `inv_host_slo` `s`
            JOIN `slo_host_map` `m` ON (
                (
                    `s`.`application` = `m`.`application_string`
                )
            )
        )
        LEFT JOIN `inv_host` `h` ON ((`m`.`host_id` = `h`.`id`))
    )
GROUP BY
    `s`.`application`
```

It's very simple, but I'm noticing some strange behavior when I query the view with a WHERE on the `date` field. If I insert `WHERE s.date = '2013-10-22'` before the `GROUP BY` statement in an actual SQL query I get 2425 records, but if I do it to the view directly:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    v_host_slo_conformance
WHERE
    date = '2013-10-22'
```

I only get 307 records.

This isn't happening on my development database and the only difference is that dev is running 5.5.15, whereas production is running 5.5.14. Is this a bug based on version differences or something I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 1):

Think about the steps.

### REAL QUERY

1. U join
2. Filter result set by where (date)
3. You group

this gives you one result set.

### IN VIEW

1. U join
2. U group by
3. THIS IS THE VIEW/RESULT SET U WORK ON
4. U filter the result set.

Two completely different result sets that you work on, obviously will give two different results.